# Flask server not working properly with CodernityDB

Tags: python, flask, codernity

I'm trying to complete the Flask tutorial between [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/) and [this](http://labs.codernity.com/codernitydb/quick.html#get-query) to have something very simple using CodernityDB instead of sqllite, and I need to execute the app to be able to study all the CodernityDB methods I need. But the server is not working properly, the localhost tell me there is an **Internal error**, but I can't figure out the way to debug it.

Here is my code (**flaskr.py**), the templates are [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/#tutorial-templates):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash
from CodernityDB.database_thread_safe import ThreadSafeDatabase
from CodernityDB.database import RecordNotFound

# configuration
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
# pending
USER = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
##app.config.from_object(__name__)

cdb = ThreadSafeDatabase(DATABASE)

if cdb.exists():
    cdb.open()
    cdb.reindex()
else:
    from database_indexes import WithXIndex
    cdb.create()
    cdb.add_index(WithXIndex(cdb.path, 'x'))

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = cdb

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
##    return "Hello World! This is powered by Python Backend."
    cur = db.get('x',10,with_doc=True)
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
##    return "Add new entry"
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    g.db.insert(dict(x=request.form['title'], name=request.form['text']))
    flash('New entrey was succesfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
##    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
##    app.run(debug= True)
##    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

**database_indexes.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from CodernityDB.hash_index import HashIndex
from CodernityDB.tree_index import TreeBasedIndex

from hashlib import md5

class WithXIndex(HashIndex):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['key_format'] = 'I'
        super(WithXIndex, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def make_key_value(self, data):
        a_val = data.get("x")
        if a_val is not None:
            return a_val, None
        return None

    def make_key(self, key):
        return key
```

I didn't create the environment variable because I want to use another approach for the configuration, maybe a file, and the config.from_object is commented because when I executed it with it shows Restarting with stat.

Comment: You either need to check your logs (where depends on how you run the app) or set debug to True.

Comment: When I execute the app the Python interface doesn't show any error, and when I set debug to True the app doesn't execute, just shows Restarting with stats.